# Issue with Undefined JSON Variable

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a basic Node.js script that creates a JSON array from a few variables and other arrays.However, whenever I call on myJSON.title in my code it does not work at all. It gives undefined. Could anyone please help me?

```
for (var i = 0; i < route.length; i++) {

  var item = {
    "title": title[i],
    "date": date[i],
    "summary": summary[i],
    "route": route[i],
    "pebbleid": "geoquery-" + timegreeting + route[i]
  };

  myarray.push(item);
  for (var i = 0; i < route.length; i++) {

    var item = {
      "title": title[i],
      "date": date[i],
      "summary": summary[i],
      "route": route[i],
      "pebbleid": "geoquery-" + timegreeting + route[i]
    };

    myarray.push(item);
  }

  myJSON = JSON.stringify({delays: myarray});

  console.log(myJSON);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the output of the `console.log(myJSON)`

Comment: Sure no problem, I'l add it now

Comment: And do you have myJSON defined outside of your for loop?

Comment: @SethMcClaine Its a global variable so yes.Regular myJSON is on the first line and the bottom line is myJSON.delays.title.

Comment: The reason `myJSON.title` is `undefined` is that `JSON.stringify` returns a string, and strings don't have a `title` property.

Comment: Thanks so much @Jordan I'm making modifications now. If you want to submit it as an actual answer, i'l be happy to mark it as accepted

Comment: One more question: I can call myJSON.delays but i can't call myJSON.delays.title @Jordan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `myJSON.title` is undefined is that `JSON.stringify` returns a string, and strings don't have a `title` property.

The object represented by the JSON string `myJSON` has a single property, `delays`, (because that's what you put in `JSON.stringify`). The value of that property is an array. Each element of that array is an object that has a `title` property (and `date`, `summary`, etc.). So to get any one `title`, you first have to retrieve the `delays` array and then retrieve one of its elements by index, and then retrieve that element's `title` property.

So for e.g. the 0th element in `delays`, you would do this:

```
obj.delays[0].title
```

I used "`obj`" because this will not work with `myJSON`, because like I said, in the code you've shown `myJSON` is a JSON string, not a JavaScript object, and so doesn't have a `delays` property.

Comment: @AgentSpyname - This Mozilla reference might help with understanding the concepts better: [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. I'm new to JSON and this was a simple and clear reply to my somewhat messy solution. Accepted for sure